# Why can't I add cookies to Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have this code:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\chromedriver");

        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

        webDriver.get("https://example.com");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder("dsdsdsds", "dsdsds").path("/").sameSite("None").expiresOn(new Date()).isSecure(true).build();

        webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        webDriver.manage().getCookies().add(cookie);

        webDriver.manage().getCookies().add(new Cookie("__Secure-access_token", accessToken));

        webDriver.manage().getCookies().add(new Cookie("__Secure-id_token", secIdToken));

        webDriver.manage().getCookies().add(new Cookie("__Secure-id_hint", idHint));
        webDriver.manage().getCookies().add(new Cookie("a12l-csrf-prod", csrfToken));
        webDriver.manage().getCookies().add(new Cookie("id_token", idToken));


        webDriver.navigate().refresh();

        webDriver.manage().getCookies().forEach(System.out::println);
```

However, after reloading, the standard page cookies are rendered, but my custom ones are not. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the cookies to the `Set` returned from `getCookies()`, you need to add it to the `WebDriver`

```
webDriver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("__Secure-access_token", accessToken));
```